# Flask: difference between @app.errorhandler(500) and @app.errorhandler(exception)

Tags: api, rest, flask, exception, handler

From my understanding, @app.errorhandler(500) changes the default error for unhandled errors, while @app.errorhandler(exception) catches all errors (except ones already specified with a handler). Doesn't that mean that both of these things achieve the same thing essentially? is there really a difference

Answer (score 1):

`@app.errorhandler(500)` would handle errors stemming from a page that returns a **HTTP status code** of 500. Whereas `@app.errorhandler(exception)` is more broad and can be used for `global exception handling`. For example if your code raises an OSError exception, this is where the exception shall be handled (unless the offending code is covered by its own try/catch block).

So it can be convenient for example to use `@app.errorhandler(404)` to customize your 404 Not found page and use `@app.errorhandler(exception)` all along for the more serious Python exceptions.

Comment: So if I am designing a REST API, would using @app.errorhandler(exception) make more sense then?

Comment: Both can be used. What is important is to return a meaningful HTTP status code along with your JSON response. So I would return a HTTP status code  of 500 in case of **exception**. If the client requests an URL/endpoint that doesn't exist, you should indeed response with a status code of 404. Using both handlers simply makes it easier to distinguish HTTP errors from Python exceptions, because you may want to handle them differently.